# Get selected options of selectbox with multiple selection in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, select

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('my_select_box');
```

This is what I use to get input values in controller in Zend Framework. When multiple selection is enabled with selectbox, this only brings one 'option.' How will I get an array of all selections user made?

I do not use Zend_Form, is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to name your element "my_select_box[]" and retrieve it as you do above.

Comment: Such a simple mistake. Thanks!